# Is there a genuine replacement in AWS for global variables?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a lambda function that accesses an external resource that can only be executed one-at-a-time for a given id. For example, it could be executed simultaneously for id=1 and id=2, but not for id=1 and id=1.

To achieve this using a Node application, we would have an in-memory state for each id, that could immediately lock when using the resource and then unlock again when not.

Unfortunately, it's this concept that is proving extremely hard to achieve in AWS due to lack of global variables. We have considered:

- Using lambda concurrency of 1 / SQS queue processing one at a time - does not work as the concurrency is not strictly limited to 1, it's 1 per group
- Storing a value in DynamoDB - not sure this works as DDB does not seem to have (m)any locking options. There is something but it looks like it's Java only and we're a JavaScript team.
- Setting up a relational database with locking - might be possible, but it would be a new tech-stack for us and feels incredibly complex for achieving something so simple

This is the second time we've hit a hurdle like this and it feels like a weakness in the platform. Can anyone advise a way to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't done (this kind of) AWS stuff so I'll just post this as a comment: You don't need locking if you have DynamoDB you can conditionally update. You can have a locking value. Setup is to have a table with rows for the IDs. Then: 1. Generate a GUID. 2. Set that GUID on the ID's row *only if* the ID doesn't currently have a GUID set on it. 3. Read the GUID for that ID. 4. If it's the one you set, do your operation, then clear it. 5. If it's not the one you set, try again. The problem with that kind of solution, though, is that inevitably you'll get IDs that get locked and never...

Comment: ...unlocked, leading to ugly "fixes" like periodically clearing locks for IDs if they've been in place for X time. But if you end up having no other choice...

Comment: What is the external resource, and can you fix that to allow concurrent requests? If not, you'll need to run a gateway to manage the requests, and yes you wouldn't do that with lambda functions but something that can have global state.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Someone else suggested a conditional update to me but I didn't quite grasp how it would be used. The read of the GUID after the attempted write is the missing piece, however. That might just work? Appreciate there would need to be cleanup though

Comment: @Bergi: We do not have control over the external resource, no. By a gateway, do you mean a stand-alone traditional application, as opposed to the serverless approach?

Comment: @Will Yes, it should be a proxy for the external resource, and it needs to be stateful which is probably easiest done using a traditional application.

Comment: Take a look at [dynamodb-lock-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-lock-client). Also, FYI, the AWS Java SDK has a [DynamoDB Lock Client](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/).

Comment: Thanks all for the useful advice, it's given me a few options there. I guess my overarching point is that to my surprise, AWS does not make this easy. I believe from something I read a while ago that Microsoft Azure has variables that can be shared between function instances?

Answer (score 0):

> Using lambda concurrency of 1 / SQS queue processing one at a time -
> does not work as the concurrency is not strictly limited to 1, it's 1
> per group

If you set up a FIFO SQS queue and send the messages with deduplication id set to your unique id you would achieve the lock with SQS.

More about it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This feature might work but is sub-optimal if I understand it correctly? As per that link, using this would mean we could only process one item per id every 5 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. For now, there's no way to change the deduplication interval - it's fixed to 5 minutes.

Comment: If that's an issue, the easiest way would be to set the lock in Redis (using AWS elastic cache).